# How to make a Plugin take the code from a js file?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've created a code to do a simple select and insert into a Database.
This code works when tested from the html on the web browser (Firefox & Chrome). 
However this was made to be a plugin, the plugin had its own errors, the json file already got corrected and it inserts the information. However there was a validation of information on the JS and the plugin is skipping this part.

The form has 5 fields that need to be filled and a radio button, after this the user would press the button "Save", The Js validates the information and if its correct it sends it to a PHP that inserts the information, this works when executed on web.
But on the plugin it skips this validation and sends the information however it its filled into the PHP for its insertion.

After searching I had already seen the guide for google extensions and firefox devs especially this one (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution)

I managed to get the message to display, however it checks the fields when you activate the plugin button not the submit button.

index_FINAL.js
*I reduced the code, just placing some lines for validation instead of all

```js
var ok = true;

function valida(f) {
    ok = true;
    var msg = "Empty fields:\n\n";

    if(f.id_own.value == "")
    {
      msg += "Ticket Owner\n ";
      ok = false;
    }
    if(f.Ticket.value == "")
    {
      msg += "Ticket ID\n";
      ok = false;
    }
    if(ok == false)
      alert(msg);
    else { }
    return ok;
  };  

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var x = document.getElementById("btn_save");
  x.addEventListener("click", valida());
});
```

index_FINAL.html
*I reduced the code, just placing the end of the html where the buttons and scripts are.

```html
 <div id="tick_but">
              <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btn_save">Save</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn_cancel">Cancel</button>
            </div>
    </form>
  </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="index_FINAL.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I try to activate the plugin I get the message generated by the js indicating that I have empty fields, instead of calling the function valida() when I click the save button.

I expect that it checks when I click the save button not before.

Answer (score 0):

The callback function `valida()` should be invoked on the submit event. The following demo is a simplified layout of what to bind to, and how to place `valida()` as the callback for the submit event. This is assuming that the `<form>` is the first one or the only `<form>` on that particular webpage (ie `index_FINAL.html`)

```js
document.forms[0].addEventListener("submit", valida);

// This is just a dummy callback for proof of concept
function valida(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.type + ' event has been triggered and callback function valida() has been invoked.');
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: OK, I tested the fragment of code that you sent me and on web browser it worked, but on the plugin I can't see the console. However on web browser I am getting to types of activations .. sort of saying, when I changed it to call the actual function valida it says undefined and submit. Like "sumbit event has been triggered and callback function valida() has been invoked" and right after that: "undefined event has been triggered and callback function valida() has been invoked"

Comment: OK now I see the undefined event that I get is because of the call of function that i have on my form. <form id="f" action="http://anubis.amxdigital.net/test/jsontest.php" method="POST" name="f" onsubmit= "return valida(this)">

Comment: Now when executing on CHROME as extension I get this error:                   
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined on the first field            if(f.id_own.value == "") , If I am not wrong this would mean that It is no longer taking the values from the html right?

Comment: `"return valida(this)"` is conflicting with the dummy `valida()` try removing the on-event attribute on `<form>` and just use `document.forms[0].addEventListener("submit", valida);` and delete the rest. Look in plugin documentation and see if it requires parameters such as `this`. Plugins normally handle `this` internally sparing us the ambiguous nature of `this`. Then again my experience with browser extensions is limited because my company's policy is users never need the use of anything but a browser, nothing extra.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Zer00ne for your response, it didnt worked for my code but i was able to see another path into solving this issue.

Since the plugins dosen't accept inline coding I removed the onsubmit function that was on the HTML form and after that I needed to make the JS available of sending the submit response to the HTML.

Here i am attaching the piece of code that I changed.

```
$(function() {
$('#btn_save').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var HTF = document.getElementById("f");
    valida(f);
    //alert(ok);
    if (ok) {
    HTF.submit();
    }
});
});
```

However the plugin dosen't works on CHROME but well it works on Firefox and that's what I needed.

Regards